# TinyMCE Editing Error: Works Locally but Fails on Server

Tags: cors, tinymce, textarea

In the past years, I've been using Tiny regularly. However, recently, I have faced issues trying to edit some fields. The situation is that I can edit the fields normally when running locally, but when transfering the files to the server, the edition isn't avaliable anymore. Although, a new apiKey has been implemented in the system to fix the problem, it still doesn't work.
This is the error that appears in the console:
invalid-origin" is not entitled to further Tiny Cloud editor loads.
All created TinyMCE editors are now configured to be read-only.

"Expectativa: TinyMCE funciona em produção após implantação"

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE documentation outlines how to resolve that issue:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/invalid-api-key/#how-can-i-resolve-the-issue-of-an-unregistered-domain

### How can I resolve the issue of an unregistered domain?

To resolve this issue, please inform your administrator and request that they review the list of approved domains on [your Tiny Account](https://www.tiny.cloud/my-account/domains/). If necessary, they will need to add the unregistered domain to the approved list. [Learn more here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/cloud-troubleshooting/#This-domain-is-not-registered-with-Tiny-Cloud.-To-continue-using-TinyMCE-a-registered-domain-is-required-starting-2024.-Please-alert-your-admin-to-review-the-approved-domains-and-add-this-one-if-required.).

### Where can I view the list of approved domains for my Tiny Cloud account?

You can view the list of approved domains by logging into [your Tiny Account](https://www.tiny.cloud/my-account/domains/). The approved domains are stored against your API Key.

Comment: It was working perfectly before, but suddenly, overnight, it stopped working. Since I can't access my old account anymore, I created a new one and added new domains and used the new key, but still, I can't edit anything

Answer (score 0):

It was working perfectly before, but suddenly, overnight, it stopped working. Since I can't access my old account anymore, I created a new one and added new domains and used the new key, but still, I can't edit anything